# Summarize more than one column in Excel COM object

Tags: excel, com, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm using SubTotal in a Openedge generated Excel book for my first time.

The example of the KB (https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Sample-Code-to-do-Excel-Grouping) is:
**chWorksheet:Range("A1"):CurrentRegion:Subtotal(1, -4112, 2, True, False, False).**

The parameters for SubTotal are:
**GroupBy , Function:, TotalList, Replace:, PageBreaks:, SummaryBelowData:**

In "TotalList" the example is 2, which means column 2 is totalized.

In VBA, TotalList can be an array. For example, Array(14, 15) indicates totaling columns 14 and 15.

But I can't make ABL  to accept that. It only receives an integer, for one column. Which is sad.

Does anybody if it's possible to totalize more than one column?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to pass the argument as an array in ABL? `Array(14, 15) ` is VBA but if you are coding this in ABL, maybe that's the reason

Comment: I thought I had tried it but it seems like I hadn't.
Now I sent an INTEGER EXTENT variable as parameter and it worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an integer, I sent an integer EXTENT variable with the column numbers and it worked perfectly.
Thanks to Tom and Jensd for the help and ideas.